# Return mysql query to nodejs flash message

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am looking to query the tracking numbers by office number.  Then pass the tracking numbers to the req.flash  in the post.  I am able to get the data to log to the console, I am having issues returning it to my main node program so I can use that data in the req.flash message.  How do I get the query results to the main javascript program so I can flash the results of the query in req.flash?

I've tried a few different calls.

Here is my output from the console

```
[nodemon] starting `node src/server.js`
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option src\server.js:20:14
App running at http://localhost:3000
Sanitized: { officeNumber: '1212' }
the output is 0
result from db is :  12121212121212
result from db is :  124563356743435
result from db is :  354466436646464
result from db is :  363548367868575
```

---

routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check')
const { matchedData } = require('express-validator/filter')
var mysql   = require('mysql'),
    config  = require("./config");

    var con = mysql.createConnection(config.db);



router.post('/trackingnumbers', [
  check('officeNumber')
    .isLength({ min:4, max:4  })
    .withMessage('That office Number doesn‘t look right')
    .trim()
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req)
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.render('trackingnumbers', {
      data: req.body,
      errors: errors.mapped()
    })
  }

  const data = matchedData(req)
  console.log('Sanitized:', data)
var mysql_query3 = require('./mysql_query.js');
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
output = "0";



function getTrackingNumbers(officeN, callback)
{
    con.query('SELECT * from trackingnumbers where office_Number = ' + officeN, function(err, result)
    {
        if (err) 
            callback(err,null);
        else
            //console.log(result);   

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              //  console.log(result[i]);
                //callback(null,result[i]);
                callback(null,result[i].tracking_Number);
            }

    });

}


//call Fn for db query with callback
 getTrackingNumbers(req.body["officeNumber"], function(err,data1){
        if (err) {
            // error handling code goes here
            console.log("ERROR : ",err);            
        } else {            
            // code to execute on data retrieval
            console.log("result from db is : ",data1);
            return data1;
        }    

});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
console.log("the output is " +  output);
  req.flash('success', 'Thanks your super cool has been inputted' + output)
  //can do 2 flashes here if need to

  res.redirect('trackingnumbers')
})





module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
getTrackingNumbers(req.body["officeNumber"], function(err,data1){
    if (err) {
        // error handling code goes here
        console.log("ERROR : ",err);            
    } else {            
        // code to execute on data retrieval
        console.log("result from db is : ",data1);
        req.flash('success', 'Data' + data1);
        return data1;
    }    
});
```

As Node is async, we will get the data only in call back.

---

**In case you want to show the message flash after redirection, you can pass the data as a query parameter**

```
res.redirect('trackingnumbers/?message=The office number is '+data )
```

Then inside the route method's body we can check for the query param 'message' & flash the message.

```
if (typeof req.query.message !== 'undefined' && typeof req.query.message.trim() != "") {
    req.flash('success', req.query.message)
}
const data = matchedData(req)
console.log('Sanitized:', data)
```

Comment: I tried that, same issue.  Here is the result.  It does let the data flash.
`code  Sanitized: { officeNumber: '1212' }
the output is 0
result from db is :  12121212121212
result from db is :  124563356743435
result from db is :  354466436646464
result from db is :  363548367868575 `

Comment: @SwimJim - ** It does let the data flash. **
Sorry, what else is needed? Do you want to print the flash message after redirection?

Please see the addition in the answer.

Comment: @SwimJim - Have you gone through https://www.npmjs.com/package/req-flash

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have gone through it, and the issue isn't flash, it's the fact I cant get an array, or object, returned out of that function.  
I followed your instructions and the query object is as follows . It's still not working                                      
`http://localhost:3000/trackingnumbers/?message=The%20office%20number%20is%20[object%20Object]`